# Tkinter: setting entry to readonly not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window with an Entry for QR Codes. The idea is the user will read the QR code with an QR Scanner, the Entry turns readonly to avoid another input from user while application do some processing. After the conclusion the Entry is editable again and the user can read another QR Code.

I created a variable `status` that controls when the Entry show be readonly or not, it works fine when the user read an QR Code and another, and another.

The problem is when I try to show a message when the user hits enter and QR code is empty or when the user reads the same QR Code in sequence. The message is shown but the Entry continues editable. In the real code various message windows are opened in this situation.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    root.geometry("850x140+10+450")
    root.resizable(0,0)

    MyFrame()
    root.mainloop()


class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.qrcode = StringVar()
        self.qrcodeEntry = None
        self.lastQrcode = ""
        # Status da tela 
        # 0 - Enabled
        # 1 - Disable (Processing)
        self.status=0

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.status=0

        root = self.master
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.qrcodeEntry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=self.qrcode)
        self.qrcodeEntry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()
        root.bind('<Return>', self.execute)

    def execute(self, *argss):
        #This call is not working
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='readonly')

        # Executes if status is 0
        if self.status == 1:
            return

        # Reset Status
        self.status=1

        # Check if QR is empty
        if (not self.qrcode.get()):
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is empty")
            return

        # Check if QR is equals last QR
        if (self.qrcode.get()==self.lastQrcode):
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is the same")

        # DO SOMETHING

        # Makes lastQrCode equals current QR
        self.lastQrcode = self.qrcode.get()


        self.master.after(3000, self.clear)       


    def clear(self):
        self.status=0        
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='normal')
        self.qrcode.set('')
        self.master.lift()
        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()

    def showCriticalError(self, title, message):
        self.master.lift()

        top = Toplevel(self.master)
        top.grab_set()
        top.title(title)
        top.geometry("650x240+10+10")
        top.resizable(0,0)
        top.transient(self.master)

        rows = 0
        while rows < 10:
            top.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            top.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            rows += 1

        Message(top, text=message, width = 500).grid(row=0,column=2, rowspan=8, columnspan=7,sticky='W')
        okButton = Button(top, text ="OK", command = top.destroy, width = 10)
        okButton.grid(row=9,column=4, columnspan=2)
        top.after(7000, top.destroy)

        self.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Instead of using a readonly Entry, why not use a Label instead?

Comment: Change to: `self.after_idle(self.qrcodeEntry.configure, {'state':'readonly'})`, dialogs are blocking, this allows the `.configure(...` to be called while the dialog is shown.

Comment: @stovfl I tried your solution but it didn`t work, but it helped me find the error. The problem was in the last line of the method ```showCriticalError``` : ```self.clear()``` this line was returning the Entry to normal state. So I removed this line and changed the ```top.after(7000, top.destroy)``` to ```top.after(7000, lambda: self.clear() or top.destroy() )``` and I did the same in the command of ```okButton```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the last line of the method `showCriticalError` : `self.clear()` this line was returning the Entry to normal state. So I removed this line and changed the `top.after(7000, top.destroy)` to `top.after(7000, lambda: self.clear() or top.destroy() )` and I did the same in the command of `okButton`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    root.geometry("850x140+10+450")
    root.resizable(0,0)

    MyFrame()
    root.mainloop()


class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.qrcode = StringVar()
        self.qrcodeEntry = None
        self.lastQrcode = ""
        # Status da tela 
        # 0 - Enabled
        # 1 - Disable (Processing)
        self.status=0

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.status=0

        root = self.master
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.qrcodeEntry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=self.qrcode)
        self.qrcodeEntry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()
        root.bind('<Return>', self.execute)

    def execute(self, *argss):
        #This call is not working
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='readonly')

        # Executes if status is 0
        if self.status == 1:
            return

        # Reset Status
        self.status=1

        # Check if QR is empty
        if (not self.qrcode.get()):
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is empty")
            return

        # Check if QR is equals last QR
        if (self.qrcode.get()==self.lastQrcode):
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is the same")

        # DO SOMETHING

        # Makes lastQrCode equals current QR
        self.lastQrcode = self.qrcode.get()


        self.master.after(3000, self.clear)       


    def clear(self):
        self.status=0        
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='normal')
        self.qrcode.set('')
        self.master.lift()
        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()

    def showCriticalError(self, title, message):
        self.master.lift()

        top = Toplevel(self.master)
        top.grab_set()
        top.title(title)
        top.geometry("650x240+10+10")
        top.resizable(0,0)
        top.transient(self.master)

        rows = 0
        while rows < 10:
            top.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            top.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            rows += 1

        Message(top, text=message, width = 500).grid(row=0,column=2, rowspan=8, columnspan=7,sticky='W')
        okButton = Button(top, text ="OK", command = lambda: self.clear() or top.destroy(), width = 10)
        okButton.grid(row=9,column=4, columnspan=2)
        top.after(7000, lambda: self.clear() or top.destroy() )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You disable the entry inside the `execute()` function. You need to call it.

*Here is what I think you need:*

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    root.geometry("850x140+10+450")
    root.resizable(0,0)

    MyFrame().execute()
    root.mainloop()


class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.qrcode = StringVar()
        self.qrcodeEntry = None
        self.lastQrcode = ""
        # Status da tela 
        # 0 - Enabled
        # 1 - Disable (Processing)
        self.status=0

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.status=0

        root = self.master
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.qrcodeEntry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=self.qrcode)
        self.qrcodeEntry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()
        root.bind('<Return>', self.execute)

    def execute(self, *argss):
        #This call is not working
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='disabled')

        # Executes if status is 0
        if self.status == 1:
            return

        # Reset Status
        self.status=1

        # Check if QR is empty
        if (not self.qrcode.get()):
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is empty")
            return

        # Check if QR is equals last QR
        if (self.qrcode.get()==self.lastQrcode):
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.showCriticalError("Message", "QR is the same")

        # DO SOMETHING

        # Makes lastQrCode equals current QR
        self.lastQrcode = self.qrcode.get()


        self.master.after(3000, self.clear)       


    def clear(self):
        self.status=0        
        self.qrcodeEntry.configure(state='normal')
        self.qrcode.set('')
        self.master.lift()
        self.qrcodeEntry.focus()

    def showCriticalError(self, title, message):
        self.master.lift()

        top = Toplevel(self.master)
        top.grab_set()
        top.title(title)
        top.geometry("650x240+10+10")
        top.resizable(0,0)
        top.transient(self.master)

        rows = 0
        while rows < 10:
            top.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            top.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            rows += 1

        Message(top, text=message, width = 500).grid(row=0,column=2, rowspan=8, columnspan=7,sticky='W')
        okButton = Button(top, text ="OK", command = top.destroy, width = 10)
        okButton.grid(row=9,column=4, columnspan=2)
        top.after(7000, top.destroy)

        self.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This displays both windows at startup.

Comment: @Ronald Yes, that may be what the OP wants.

Comment: I understood the question was about the Entry field that didn't disable when the pop-up appears?

Comment: Yes, I disabled it when the program starts @Ronald